# excel comparing dates error

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a table with dates:

```
        A
3    5/05/2020  
4    5/05/2020
```

and the formula in column B is:
=IF(A4<>A3,"true","false")

Since dates are the same I expect to get a FALSE, but I am getting TRUE
I have four different tables, and this works as expected in three of them, but does not work for the 4th.
Not sure what to look into, checked formatting.

Edit:
If formatted as General it shows:

```
43956.91667
43956.95833
```

Tried this with other working tables and they have:
43986

How would I format them to be the same? I tried Decrease Decimal option, but it rounds 6/05/2020 to be the same as 5/05/2020

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem from the information you provide.  What do you see in A3:A4 if you format the cells as `General`?

Comment: You will need to truncate the value. Formatting only changes what you see, not what is in the cell.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld thank you, this was driving me nuts, all sorted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your dates are, or were, originally added as dates and times. Rounding the values in your formula down to the nearest whole number will make them a date value rather than a date/time value. Try this:

`=IF(ROUNDDOWN(A4,0)<>ROUNDDOWN(A3,0),"true","false")`